# How to generate xml documentation file in ios xamarin studio?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin-studio

How to generate `xml` documentation file in `iOS` `xamarin` studio, I am working on `xamarin` studio on `iPhone` application in this how can I generate the documentation file of my code in `xml` format as we usually do in `visual studio -> Properties -> Build -> Xml` Documentation file as shown in the image below, How to achieve this in `xamarin` studio

Thanks in advance.

.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it is the right way or not but still i got it, Just load the project in visual studio go to properties of the project in the solution explorer in that go to build and there you can see the XML documentation file check box check that, As i have shown in the above image in the question, Every thing is same as like we do in visual studio to generate the XML documentation but the thing is the visual studio should be installed with Xamarin Studio Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there seems to be no native way of doing this within Xamarin Studio. However, there is details in the following link on how to achieve this:

[Mono Documentation Creation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/monodoc/generating-documentation/)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in document generation in Xamarin Studio. Once I used [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) for a Xamarin.Android app's documentation and it worked pretty great so I would recommend that.